# How to check if an ImageView was loaded with a picture image from a URL

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, picasso

I am trying to check whether an **`ImageView`** was loaded with an image, and that the URL actually had an image resource.

```
ImageView dynamicImageView = new ImageView(context)
Picasso.get()
.load(myURL)
.resize(myWidth, myWidth)
.centerCrop()
.into(dynamicImageView, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Drawable drawable = dynamicImageView.getDrawable();
        boolean hasImage = (drawable != null);

        if (hasImage && (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
            hasImage = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() != null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {

    }
});
```

This always returns true since Picasso automatically fills the default drawable placeholder into the `dynamicImageView`.

How should I go about it so that I always get a **"truthful"** result where the URL had no image resource?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You can use Target callback from Picasso API

Answer (score 2):

You can go with Target callback:

```
private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {       
      }
      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed() {
      }
}
```

And while loading image, you need to write:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(myURL).into(target);
```

Just for the information:

- `onBitmapLoaded()` mostly used to perform image operations before we load into the view actually.
- `Picasso.LoadedFrom` describes where the image was loaded from, whether it's MEMORY, DISK or NETWORK.